# Nginx bind to external IP only (listen hostname:port)

Tags: nginx, ip, hostname, reverse-dns

I'd like to specify an nginx server that listens only on external IP of an hostname given in `listen` directive. My server has domain name `foobar.example.com` which resolves to public IP `1.2.3.4`.

When I configure nginx server like this

```
server {

    #listen 3330;
    listen foobar.example.com:3330;
    server_name foobar.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.1.0.1:3330;
        proxy_set_header  Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }
}
```

it listens on `127.0.0.1:3330` though. Why is that? How can I make it to bind to `1.2.3.4:3330` instead without hardcoding the IP address in the config file?

```
# dig +noall +answer foobar.example.com
foobar.example.com.     2648    IN  A   1.2.3.4
# dig +noall +answer -x 1.2.3.4
4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa. 2828  IN  PTR foobar.example.com.
# dig +noall +answer -x 127.0.0.1
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. 0   IN  PTR foobar.example.com.
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. 0   IN  PTR foobar.
```

Just FYI: When I use just `listen 3330` and keep the rest unchanged, nginx listens on `0.0.0.0:3330` and, as you suspect, all hell breaks loose on first request to `http://foobar.example.com:3330`. :-)

Comment: Pick another port.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I won't.

Comment: If you're just trying to make your own life difficult, then by all means do so. But this is no less valid a solution than any other, and probably the best possible solution.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question though.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out problem was that I've left the following in `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost foobar.example.com.
```

and I've already forgotten how it got there. :-) Removing `foobar.example.com.` alias of 127.0.0.1 made nginx configured with the snippet above listen on external IP only as I expected.